# Do headshots increase tranquilization effects?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

When trying to knock out a creature before you tame it, is it a good idea or bad idea to aim for a headshot? This seems to increase the damage done to the creature, which is bad, but does it enhance the tranquilization effect (e.g. raise torpor faster)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my personal experience yes, headshots increase torpor effects. This is supported by the wiki [crossbow article](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Crossbow).

> Most creatures will take about 2.5 times as much damage if you shoot them in the head. Torpor gain from Tranquilizer Arrows does scale with this boost

Rapidly increasing a creature's torpor has a few benefits. First, this will reduce the time dinos have to attack you. Second, conservation of ammo. 2 headshots  are the equivalent of 5 body shots. With torpor this effect is magnified as one body shot worth of torpor could wear out by the time you can hit with 4 more shots.